# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm following along in a book called Machine Learning in Action. I encounted a problem in chapter 5. When I run:

```
def plotBestFit(wei):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    wei = np.mat(wei)
    weights = wei.getA()
    dataMat, labelMat = loadDataSet()
    dataArr = np.array(dataMat)
    n = np.shape(dataArr)[0]
    xcord1 = []; ycord1 = []
    xcord2 = []; ycord2 = []
    for i in range(n):
        if int(labelMat[i]) == 1:
            xcord1.append(dataArr[i,1]);ycord1.append(dataArr[i,2])
        else:
            xcord2.append(dataArr[i,1]);ycord2.append(dataArr[i,2])
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.scatter(xcord1, ycord1, s=30, c='red', marker = 's')
        ax.scatter(xcord2, ycord2, s=30, c='green')
        x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
        y = (-weights[0] - weights[1]*x)/weights[2]
        ax.plot(x,y)
        plt.xlabel('X1');plt.ylabel('X2');
        plt.show()
```

It errors:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "F:\python2.7.12\lib\logRegres.py", line 59, in plotB
>     y = (-weights[0] - weights[1]*x)/weights[2]
> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
> ```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  There are too many unknown inputs here for anyone to debug.

Comment: the code is part of the project that contains much code.

Comment: Hello, thank  for your advice.but  don't allow much code  in the input.could you give me your email account?

Comment: Best guess is `wei` that you input is a scalar, so it turned into a `1x1` ndarray `weights` which can't be indexed beyond `weights[0]`.  i.e. the error isn't in this part of the code

Comment: >>> from numpy import *
>>> reload(logRegres)
<module 'logRegres' from 'F:\python2.7.12\lib\logRegres.pyc'>
>>> dataArr, labelMat = logRegres.loadDataSet()
>>> weights = logRegres.stocGradAscent0(array(dataArr), labelMat)
>>> weights
array([ 1.01702007,  0.85914348, -0.36579921])

Comment: weights=array([ 1.01702007,  0.85914348, -0.36579921])

Comment: weights is wei,1x3 array

Comment: Well, that's what I get for trying to help without a [mcve]

Comment: @曹传桂 You need to read and understand [ask] and why it is important to provide a [mcve]. At the end it is your own choice, but if you want to increase chances of finding help here, you may want to stick to those rules.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnes I see. sorry about this problem.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, you just need to [edit] your question accordingly.